# Dynamic url response to captured using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var urlArray = ["api/vehicle?sttime=1424044800&endtime=1424390400","api/vehicle?type=travel&stt‌​ime=1424476800&endtime=1424822400","api/vehicle/?type=travel&sttime=1424908800&en‌​dtime=1425859199"] 

function succ(eachurl) {
   return _.http.get(eachurl);
   //calling ajax using _.http.get(url)
}
var ps = _.map(urlArray, succ); 
//and ps will be [{"readyState":1},{"readyState":1},{"readyState":1}] 

 $.when.apply($, ps).always(alwaysFun);
```

when ever i will call $.when function will hit server based on array size which is dynamic and calls.

```
 function alwaysFun(res1, res2, res3) { 
     //works fine prints all the three responses from 3 urls
    console.log(res1);
    console.log(res2);
    console.log(res3);
 }
```

But my Doubt is if the array is dynamic containing 10 urls [A, B ...Z]
and the response will also 10 responses and how can i will capture it in call back function if it is dyanamic array of url are hitted.
here my approach for the dynamic  array urls;

```
 ps = [A, b...z];      
 $.when.apply($, ps).always(alwaysFun);
 //How can i will mention dynamic responses in call back please
 function alwaysFun(res1, res2 ....resZ) { 
     //Please guide on this issue
 }
```

Comment: I suppose [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) will save the world.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), it is a special type of array like object which has an indexed list of all arguments passed to the method.

```
function alwaysFun(res1, res2, res3) {
    //works fine prints all the three responses from 3 urls
    console.log(res1);
    console.log(res2);
    console.log(res3);
    //user

    console.log('using arguments')
    $.each(arguments, function (i, arg) {
        console.log(arg)
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vsx1Lkft/)